# Make form labels dynamic based on selected language

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I want to create a aspx page using c# which can be displayed in English and Dutch both languages.

Can any one give me any idea how to do it?

Comment: Well, this is how you start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this tutorial

Walkthrough: Using Resources for Localization with ASP.NET

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f(v=vs.90).aspx